# Retain Skobbler MapViewHolder

Tags: android, android-fragments, skobbler-maps

i have an activity with a TabLayout and a ViewPager. Each Tab represents one Fragment. I implemented the SKMapViewHolder(skobbler) in my Fragment and it works fine. But each time when i rotate my screen the MapView will be recreated. How can i retain it?

Here the Code:

fragment_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
        android:id="@+id/map_surface_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
public class NavigationFragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String TAG=NavigationFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private SKMapSurfaceView mapView;
    private SKMapViewHolder mapHolder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setRetainInstance(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate executed");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView executed");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
        mapHolder = (SKMapViewHolder) view.findViewById(R.id.map_surface_holder);
        SKMapSurfaceView mapView = mapHolder.getMapSurfaceView();
        MapSurfaceListener mapSurfaceListener = new MapSurfaceListener(this.mapView);
        mapHolder.setMapSurfaceListener(mapSurfaceListener);
        //view.setSaveEnabled(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapHolder.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapHolder.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState executed");
    }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SKPrepareMapTextureListener {

    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Bind(R.id.viewpager)
    ViewPager viewPager;
    @Bind(R.id.tab_layout)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate executed");
        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            prepareSKTextures();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        hideSystemUI();
        setupViewPager();
        TabIcon.configureTabIcons(MainActivity.this, tabLayout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }

    private void setupViewPager() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                MainActivity.this));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void prepareSKTextures() {
        final SKPrepareMapTextureThread prepThread = new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, App.skMapsResourcesPath, "SKMaps.zip", this);
        prepThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapTexturesPrepared(boolean b) {
        if(b) {
            SKMapsInitSettings initMapSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
            SKMapViewStyle skMapViewStyle = new SKMapViewStyle(App.skMapsResourcesPath + "daystyle/", "daystyle.json");
            initMapSettings.setMapResourcesPaths(App.skMapsResourcesPath, skMapViewStyle);
            SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this, initMapSettings);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
        //SKMaps.getInstance().destroySKMaps();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Just added one line to my activity in the AndroidManifast:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```